# Does anyone know rails database adapter for SQL Server which is using ODBC driver and which should also work on rails 5.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, odbc, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to upgrade rails from rails 4.2 to 5.x which is using SQL Server with ODBC driver. And the adapter which is used to connect the database is activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.

But, unfortunately recent version of gem [activerecord-sqlserver-adapter](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter) isn't supporting ODBC Driver anymore. I am forced to move to TinyTDS. Is there any alternate gem available which can be used with rails 5.0 + SQLServer with ODBC driver?

Any help on this is really appreciated. I have tried enough searching for the gems.

Comment: I'd give [`localytics/odbc_adapter`](https://github.com/localytics/odbc_adapter) a shot.

Comment: We ended up patching the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter https://github.com/lranj/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/tree/5-0-stable-with-odbc